# Keep Two Text Values Vertically aligned in React Native

Tags: android, ios, css, react-native

I'm doing a project where I have to manage 6 texts values. Each pair has to be aligned vertically. As an example check below.

```
 Latest    Old     New
  6M       10      20K
```

As shown in above example, Text Value call `Latest` has to be aligned with `6M` where `6M` text value change over time. So keeping these two text values vertically aligned is a must. Same concept applies to other two columns.

Also, Since there are 3 columns only, These should evenly use Device display width.

**My Code**

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
     <View style={{flexDirection:'column',alignItems:'flex-start',paddingTop:1,paddingBottom:3}}>
     {
        this.state.fontLoaded ? (
        <Text style={{fontSize:14,minWidth:getWidth()*0.25}}>Latest</Text>    // Select K or M or B or T
        ) : null
     }
     </View>
     <View style={{flexDirection:'column',alignItems:'flex-start',paddingTop:1,paddingBottom:3}}>
     {
         this.state.fontLoaded ? (
         <Text>6M</Text>    // Select K or M or B or T
         ) : null
     }
  </View>
 </View>
</View>
```

`getWidth()` function returns Device display width. I wanted to make this program responsive to all iOS and Android display sizes. That's why I used `getWidth()` function.

**Output**

Below sketch kind of similar to what I receive by above code.

```
Latest
    6M
```

**Problem**

As in above code, when I change `6M` value, it does not align with `Latest` text. Also if I duplicate above code to generate other two columns, It makes everything a mess. What am I missing here? How can I change my code to get what I required?

Comment: What do you mean by it makes everything a mess?

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara All the other components of the screen also get out of aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [Flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox) {justifyContent: 'space-evenly'} or {justifyContent: 'space-between'} and [Text style](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#style) {textAlign:'right'}

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this code.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

export default class VerticalAlignText extends Component {

  constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state =
      {
        data: [
          { "id": "1", "lable": "Latest", "value": "6M" },
          { "id": "2", "lable": "Old", "value": "10" },
          { "id": "3", "lable": "New", "value": "20K" },
        ]
      }
  };

  renderData() {
    return ( 
      <View 
        style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row',}}>
        {this.state.data.map((item) =>
          <View
            key={item.id}
            style={{
              flex:1,
              alignItems:"center"
            }}>
            <Text> {item.lable}</Text>
            <Text> {item.value}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    )
  }
   
  handleOnPress(){
    let clonedData = this.state.data.slice();
    clonedData.map((item)=>{
      if(item.lable === "Latest"){
        item.value = item.value === "50K" ? "6M" : "50K";
      }
      return item;
    })
   
    this.setState({data: clonedData});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#0d98ba" }}>
        {this.state.data.length ? this.renderData() : null}
        <Button
          onPress={()=> this.handleOnPress()}
          title={"changeLatest"}
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```